# Modifying List View in C# Doesn't Work?

Tags: 2010, development, list-view

I am trying to modify a view for a list in a Feature Event Receiver. The list is created in the same function; and the columns all added to it. When I look in the List Settings via the web interface, the Fields are there, but the following code doesn't seem to work:

```
SPView view = list.Views[0];
view.ViewFields.Add("Value");
view.Update();
```

Going from the [MSDN Documentation on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spviewfieldcollection%28v=office.14%29.aspx) I really can't see what I'm doing wrong. No exceptions are being thrown, the list only has the one view, so... any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I usually retreive the View via it's ID like this:

```
 var view = list.Views[list.DefaultView.ID];
 view.ViewFields.Add("Value");
 view.Update();
```

Or like this:

```
SPView view = list.DefaultView;
view.ViewFields.Add("Value");
view.Update();
```

But to get it by Views[0] should work to.

What comes to mind is that the Field name may possibly be incorrect. Have you tried debugging your code to see if it breaks?

Comment: The field name is correct; if the field name is incorrect it throws an error (I tested this by changing the field name to something incorrect).

Comment: Great, and I assume you also do a list.Update() before adding the viewfields?

Comment: Using the field object directly (it is created earlier in the function), also doesn't work.

Comment: Yes; list.Update() is called numerous times before this point, and after.

Comment: The behavior is odd to me! Just one question, why are you calling list.Update() after this code?

Comment: To see if it made a difference to this; it doesn't, so I'll probably prune it out later.

Comment: Did you check if list.View[0] is actually a visible html view of your list?

Comment: in what situation wouldn't it be? There's only the one view on the list.

Comment: That isn't really true AFAIK. At least when you create a list in VS, it starts with a default view, and a default mobile view, and a couple other weird views that I don't really know what they are for. View[0] is probably the Mobile view if looking at a random custom list definition schema is any guide.